# How to recognise non letter from a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi all :) I'm building a script to code text with a simple text rotation(ROT).
The script works well, but I'm having a problem, it also rotates all symbols like [spaces,!,?,.] I'm working with ascii table to do it, what can i do to avoid rotating that type of characters?

```
def rot13(input,key): #Function to code a text with caeser chyper.
    if key > 25:
        key = 25
    elif key < 2:
        key = 2
    finaltext = ''
    for letter in input:
        num = ord(letter)
        if (num + key) > 122: #If the final number is greater than 122..
            x = (num + key) - 122
            finaltext += chr(x + ord('a') - 1)
        elif((num + key <= 122)):
            finaltext += chr(num + key)
    print(finaltext)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

before "rotating" your character, add a check to see whether or not it is alphanumeric:

```
if letter.isalpha():
    # Do your thing
else:
    finaltext += letter
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
>>> import string
>>> letter = 'a'
>>> letter in string.letters
True
>>> letter = '.'
>>> letter in string.letters
False
```